# Why won't default potgresql text search parser tokenize Georgian words?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-14, georgian

I am trying to get postgresql full text search work with the Georgian language. I created a dictionary:

```sql
create text search dictionary georgian_hunspell(...);
```

and a configuration with the default parser:

```sql
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION georgian_hunspell_configuration (parser = default);
```

But the default parser won't tokenize Georgian words, instead it recognizes them as "Space symbols". Why? Georgian uses letters just like most of the languages. It doesn't have characters like say Chinese, it's just words separated by space. And also Georgian letters are present in the UTF-8 table.

Executing `ts_debug` shows this:

- Some random sequence of English letters is recognized as "Word, all ASCII":

```sql
select * from ts_debug('georgian_hunspell_configuration', 'dsfasdfs');
```

- Some random sequence of English and say German/Swedish letters is recognized as "Word, all letters":

```sql
select * from ts_debug('georgian_hunspell_configuration', 'äpfasdfpeltäfasdf');
```

- Some random sequence of Armenian letters is also recognized as "Word, all letters":

```sql
select * from ts_debug('georgian_hunspell_configuration', 'կդտըպլՔՂԱ');
```

- But some random or meaningful sequence of Georgian letters is recognized as "Space symbols":

```sql
select * from ts_debug('georgian_hunspell_configuration', 'ასდადფ');
```

Why does that happen? Since the default parser won't define the token type correctly, the token in question is not looked up against my dictionaries, therefore the search fails.

This is my postgrsql version:
PostgreSQL 14.7 on aarch64-apple-darwin20.6.0, compiled by Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9), 64-bit

Comment: What is the Ctype of the database you are connected to?  (`\l+` in psql)

Comment: @jjanes encoding UTF-8, collate en_US.UTF-8, ctype en_US.UTF-8. Does the problem lies in this?

Comment: It worked for me with that encoding/ctype on ubuntu.  I can't test on mac, maybe the issue is peculiar to mac.  But my terminal doesn't render Georgian characters, so I'm not 100% they got pasted in correctly--but if they were not pasted correctly I would assume they would also not be considered "word, all letters" like they were, but rather some kind of control characters.

Comment: @jjanes can you give me the result of the query you tried?

I don't know if this is specific to macOS, but I tried reproducing it on https://www.db-fiddle.com/ which didn't work. It still recognizes it as space symbols. And I also tried doing the same on https://uibakery.io/sql-playground which gives strange results: it recognizes the words but also finds them all in the dictionary "english_stem" regardless of what language is used

Comment: db-fiddle seems to use SQL_ASCII for the encoding and C for the ctype, so it isn't surprising that that doesn't work.  If I use that, I also get it considered space symbols.  With en_US.UTF8, I get 'Word, all letters'.  The reported dictionary for it is whatever dictionary my config uses, english_stem, french_stem, etc.